# How to allocate specific number of bytes in a char array - memory management

Tags: c++, c, arrays, char, byte

I have a char array that I'm using as a memory pool.  I already have all the bytes flagged to signify that they are free/not free.  My question is how do I go about allocating 4 bytes of the array for each int?

Small example of how I'm thinking this will work:

```
void* block;
char memPool[50];

block = &memPool[0];
return block;
```

This will return a pointer to a location that is big enough to hold 1 byte if I'm thinking correctly.  So maybe I can use a void* array of 4 bytes instead and loop through the bytes until I get to the sizeof whatever type I'm being passed.  I'm just trying to get this hashed out on paper before I sit down and start coding it.

I'm just looking for a bit of insight.  Thanks.

Comment: Your block can hold 50 bytes and your code returns a pointer to that block. I'm not sure where you get 1 byte from, or what you mean by a void* array of 4 bytes. I think you have some misunderstandings.

Comment: Am I incorrect in thinking that memPool[0] can only hold 1 byte?

Comment: No, but you return `&memPool[0]` which is a pointer to a block of 50 bytes.

Comment: Usually, `sizeof(char)` is 1. This is correct, but a pointer, even `void*` usually has a size of 4.

Comment: @RileyF I guess you are misunderstanding that `char memPool[50];` is a block of fifty contiguous bytes, and a pointer to any one of those bytes can be used to access any of the other bytes. Any pool allocator would normally take advantage of this, you seem to be trying to work around it.

Comment: Ah, there's my misunderstanding then.  So if I returned another block and gave it &memPool[4] would that still give me the same 50byte block or would it only be 46?  Also, I didn't realize void* had a size of 4 bytes.  That's my fault for not checking that.  Thanks.

Comment: @RileyF `&memPool[4]` would be a pointer to the fourth byte (counting from zero) of the same fifty byte block. So there would be 46 bytes after the pointer and 4 before it.

Comment: Awesome.  Thanks for the clarification.  I'm extremely new to memory management using char arrays.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The memory allocated is contiguous so you can iterate through the indices with the pointer hence you have the whole 50 blocks.

```
void* block; //the pointer
char memPool[50]; //the contiguous memory location allocated 

block = &memPool[0]; //the pointer is holding the address of 0th index, hence the whole memory location
return block;
```

Comment: Thanks for all the help.  I got everything figured out.  I was just thinking in the wrong mindset.  Creating the memory manager using a char array wasn't nearly as hard as I made it out to be.  Just had to be a bit creative.